# Pixel matrix how to scale

Tags: c

I'm doing a sierpinski's carpet program and i managed to create a PGM image from a matrix.I first create a char **matrix which has # or ' ' .# = white color , ' ' = black color, and then i create a int **pixels with values 0 or 255 for black and white, pretty simple. The matrix size is equal to number of iterations of sierpinski's carpet : for 3 iterations of the algorithm i have a resulting matrix(so image) of 27 by 27 pixels. How can i multiply this matrix in order to enlarge the resulting picture but keep the same image.Something like for each pixel i want it to be  4 pixels in the output image. C program.

EDIT: Code for printing a PGM image from a matrix of pixel values

```
void print(char fout[30],int **pixels,int width,int height){

int i,j;
FILE *f = fopen(fout,"w");
fprintf(f,"%s\n","P2");
fprintf(f,"%d %d\n",width,height);
fprintf(f,"%d\n",255);
for(i=height-1;i>=0;i--){
        for(j=0;j<width;j++){
                fprintf(f,"%d ",pixels[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(f,"\n");
}

fclose(f);
```

}

Code for creating the pixel value matrix

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        if(basegrid[i][j] == ' ')
            pixels[i][j]=0;
        else
            pixels[i][j]=255;
```

Comment: Instead of describing the code, please show the (relevant) code you have problems with. You might want read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: I added code to show you what i'm doing but what i'm asking is for a way to enlarge the resulting image. I haven't coded anything on this part because i don't know where to start, hence the question i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can create a larger matrix (of size: size * 2 by size * 2) and then fill it according to the pixels you had at first.

Something like this should work:

```
int main()
{
    int **pixels;
    int size;
    int **enlarged;

    int idx;
    enlarged = malloc(2 * size * sizeof(int *));
    for(idx = 0; idx != size; ++idx)
    {
        enlarged[idx] = malloc(2 * size * sizeof(int));
    }

    int row;
    int col;
    for(row = 0; row != size; ++row)
    {
        for(col = 0; col != size; ++col)
        {
            enlarged[row * 2][col * 2] = pixels[row][col];
            enlarged[row * 2 + 1][col * 2] = pixels[row][col];
            enlarged[row * 2][col * 2 + 1] = pixels[row][col];
            enlarged[row * 2 + 1][col * 2 + 1] = pixels[row][col];
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I left out the code where you read size and fill pixels.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much , this works. I assume if i want to scale the picture 4 times it's the same process only i need to do all combinations of row*4+1 , +2 etc , right ?

Comment: I assumed a pixel is squared, so 4 times a pixel gives 4 pixels, which is a 2 by 2 matrix. If you would like to have, for example, pixels that are 3 by 3 then you can add more combinations.

Comment: Yes i added something like 2 more for loops each for 0->scaling_factor and done something like enlarged[row*factor+iter1][column*factor+iter2]=pixels[i][j] so i get all the combinations for whatever scaling factor i choose. Thanks again